# Mirror SpriteKit node that has pinned children

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

The question could also be: How to mirror a pinned SpriteKit node along another nodes axis?

I'm developing a 2D platform game with SpriteKit. My hero is a SKNode that functions as container for all the body parts.

```
hero:SKNode
--- leftArm:SKSpriteNode
--- rightArm:SKSpriteNode
--- body:SKSpriteNode
```

leftArm and rightArm are pinned to the body node (through SKPhysicsJointPin).

I want to mirror my hero horizontally when he changes his direction. When I change xScale to -1 everything gets mirrored but the pinned nodes are mirrored along its own axis and not along the bodies axis/parent nodes center.

I tried to manually adjust the pinned nodes position but without any effect (seems not be allowed for pinned nodes).

How can I mirror my pinned nodes along the body nodes axis or change its position   independently?

Answer (score 0):

I found an approach that worked for me to change a pinned node's position independently.

1. Adjust your pinned nodes position
2. Get your pinned nodes joint(s) (through
   pinnedNode.physicsBody.joints)
3. Remove the joint from your physicsWorld
4. Create a new joint with the same parameters as the removed one and
   add it to the world